WCF, SOAP, The 'Body', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' required message part was not encrypted
I'm trying to receive requests from a client. When the client sends a request, he receives the following error:
An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
When i check my tracelog, i see the following line:
The 'Body', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' required message part  was not encrypted.
This is what i do in my Code-Section for configuring the server:
private void RunServiceOasisCompat()
{
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri(_config.LocalEndpointSpri);
    //Create the ServiceHost
    _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SpriService), baseAddress);

    Binding binding = null;

    if (_config.LocalEndpointSpri.StartsWith("https"))
    {
        binding = CreateServiceBindingOasis();
    }
    else
    {
        binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    }
    ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint =
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(SpriPort), binding, _config.LocalEndpointSpri);

    if (_host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate != null)
        _log.WriteLog(info, "This is the current (default) service credentials certificate's distinguished name: " + _host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate.SubjectName.Name);

    _host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
        X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
    _host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate =
        GetCertificateFromStore(_config.SpriLocalSignatureCertSubject);

    // add client certificate thumbprint for internal authorization
    var ccert = GetCertificateFromStore(_config.SpriRemoteSignatureCertSubject);
    SpriService.ClientThumbprint = ccert.Thumbprint;
    _clientThumbprint = ccert.Thumbprint;

    //Enable metadata publishing
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = _host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    //If not, add one
    if (smb != null)
    {
        _host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(smb);
    }
    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    if (_config.LocalEndpointSpri.StartsWith("https"))
    {
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = false;
        smb.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        // Add MEX endpoint
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(
            ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
            //MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding(), // HTTPS
            "mex"
        );
    }
    else
    {
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.HttpsGetEnabled = false;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        // Add MEX endpoint
        _host.AddServiceEndpoint(
            ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
            "mex"
        );

    }



    SpriService._controlStampIssuer =
        _config.SpriOverrideIssuer != null && _config.SpriOverrideIssuer.Length > 0
            ? _config.SpriOverrideIssuer
            : _host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate.Subject;
    if (_host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate != null)
    {
        SpriService._controlStampSerial = _host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate.SerialNumber;
        SpriService._controlStampMajorRelease = _config.SpriMajorRelease;
        SpriService._controlStampMinorRelease = _config.SpriMinorRelease;
    }
    else
        _log.WriteLog(error, "Could not get service credential certificate.");

    // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages.
    try
    {
        _host.Open();
        _log.WriteLog(info, "host open succesfully");
    }
    catch (Exception xcp)
    {
        _log.WriteLog(error, "host open \n" + xcp.Message + Environment.NewLine + xcp.StackTrace);
    }

    SpriService.EventInboundOrderSpri += SpriService_EventInboundOrderSpri;
    SpriService.EventInboundMessageSpri += SpriService_EventInboundMessageSpri;

}

CustomBinding CreateServiceBindingOasis()
{
    //Setup custom binding with HTTPS + Body Signing + Soap1.1
    CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();

    //HTTPS Transport
    HttpsTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();

    var asecb = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
    asecb.IncludeTimestamp = false;
    asecb.LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = false;
    asecb.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToInitiator);
    asecb.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient);
    asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;
    asecb.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
    asecb.AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = true;
    asecb.RequireSignatureConfirmation = false;
    //asecb.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
    asecb.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
    asecb.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;

    switch (_config.WsSecurityAlgorithmSuite.ToLower())
    {
        case null:
        case "":
        case "basic256":
            // this is the default setting
            // binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;
            break;
        case "basic128":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128;
            break;
        case "basic128rsa15":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Rsa15;
            break;
        case "basic128sha256":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Sha256;
            break;
        case "basic128sha256rsa15":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Sha256Rsa15;
            break;
        case "basic192":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic192;
            break;
        case "basic192rsa15":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic192Rsa15;
            break;
        case "basic192sha256":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic192Sha256;
            break;
        case "basic192sha256rsa15":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic192Sha256Rsa15;
            break;
        case "basic256rsa15":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Rsa15;
            break;
        case "basic256sha256":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256;
            break;
        case "basic256sha256rsa15":
            asecb.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256Rsa15;
            break;
        default:
            _log.WriteLog(error, $"Unknown HashAlgorithm '{_config.WsSecurityAlgorithmSuite}', possible values are: <empty>, SHA-1, SHA256");
            break;
    }

    //Setup for SOAP 11 and UTF8 Encoding
    TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);

    //Bind in order (Security layer, message layer, transport layer)
    binding.Elements.Add(asecb);
    binding.Elements.Add(textMessageEncoding);
    binding.Elements.Add(transport);

    return binding;
}

Additional Info: It is basic256 and only https.
Anyone know what i have to adjust on my side so my service can receive the request?
I used CustomBinding because SOAP 1.1 is used but with additional WS-Security.

Ensure that the version and policy of WS-Security are compatible with the implementation of the client and server. You can refer to the specific version of WS-Security and the policies used to make sure that they are consistent. In the meantime, I suggest you check on Postman to see what exactly you're sending out. Check if it's a problem with the server.
